# Phonegap 3.6.3 connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to run phonegap connection code. This is my script and i have installed network plugin.

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

```
function onDeviceReady()
 {
    checkConnection();
}

function onBodyLoad() {
  alert('body load');
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    alert('checkConnection');
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

But i am getting  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

Could any one please suggest where am i going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I see you call checkConnection twice. Is onDeviceReady really called? could you try to remove the checkConnection on `onBodyLoad()`?

Comment: Even if i remove the onBodyLoad() then also it is showing same error.

Comment: Have you included `cordova.js` in your index.html?

Comment: yes i have included cordova.js